# eager_load gives a NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby on Rails v4.0.3 (Ruby 2.1.0p0) and this afternoon my project was completely working, until I decided to clean up my controllers and their routes (custom controllers and routes for admin and user pages).

Now, that all worked fine in my development build, but I could not start the application on my webserver (using Apache en Passenger). When starting the application, it gives me the following error:

```
uninitialized constant PayPal::SDK::REST::API::V1 (NameError)
  /Volumes/Projects/iosfy/website/app/controllers/api/v1/query_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `each'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:464:in `block in eager_load!'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `each'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:462:in `eager_load!'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:347:in `eager_load!'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
  /Users/depl0y/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
...
more stack trace ending in my environment.rb (Application.initialize!)
```

The funny thing is that there is no reference to the PayPal SDK in my query_controller.

Once I turn off eager_load in my configuration file, the website runs like it should (including the API, mentioned in the error).

I suspect my routes to be the cause of this error:

```
constraints :subdomain => /^api.*/ do
    namespace :api, path: nil, defaults: {format: "json"} do
        namespace :v1 do

            match '/settings', to: 'query#settings', via: 'get'
...more routes

        end
    end
end
```

Because the API::V1 isn't part of the PayPal SDK.

Can someone give me any pointers on where to look? I looked around for 2 hours, but I cannot seem to find the cause of this.

---

**EDIT:**
Ok, after some experimenting, it seems that indeed my query_controller is at fault here.

I gave my query_controller the API::V1:: prefix (because of the route?) and removing that makes my application start again. So, the application starts again, but calling the API is now a problem.

Wehn I call it, it still gives me the following error:

```
uninitialized constant PayPal::SDK::REST::API::V1
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, it seems that my namespace API clashes with a namespace PayPal uses (API) and therefor stuff crashes and burns.

Renaming my namespace for my API to "Service" magically made it work. I would really love to see a solution for this problem though.

How can I correctly separate my namespace "API::V1" from the PayPal::SDK::REST::API namespace?

Comment: did you try making the namespace in your controller absolute? `::API::V1` or are you not using it at all? you don't have enough example code in here to make good assumptions.